# AngularJs how to strip trailing slash

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing, angular-routing

I have defined a url state with 2 parameters, one is optional, like this:

```
.state('productsByCategory', {
            url: '/products/:catSlug/:subCatSlug?',
            controller: 'ProductCtrl',
            templateUrl: '/app/products/list.html',
        })
```

And I am generating the links like this:

```
<a ui-sref="productsByCategory({
    catSlug: 'main-category', subCatSlug: 'sub-category'
})">Sub category</a>
```

This generates a url like `href="/products/main-category/sub-category"` (perfect)

```
<a ui-sref="productsByCategory({
    catSlug: 'main-category', subCatSlug: null
})">Main category</a>
```

This generates a url like `href="/products/main-category/"` - with an extra trailing `/`!

I want this url to be: `href="/products/main-category"`

My question: how can I strip the trailing slash when no `subCatSlug` is provided?

Thanks

Comment: seems normal, the `/` doesn't change the meaning of the URL, is there some reason that it's important that it isn't there?

Comment: 2 reasons, the first is purely aesthetic, the second is that my Symfony app won't match the url with a trailing slash. I know it is possible to fix that quite easily but then I need to consider canonical urls and redirects etc. It would be much neater if I could fix it here. Can't see any obvious way to do it though...

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/50

Answer (score 2):

After much digging into the `ui-router` I changed it up a bit and gave up on trying to strip the trailing slash. Instead I'm taking just one slug and putting that slug together in the `ui-sref`:

```
.state('productsByCategory', {
        url: '/products/{slug:any}',
        controller: 'ProductCtrl',
        templateUrl: '/app/products/list.html',
    })
```

The `any` bit is important as it stops the `/` from getting encoded.

```
<a ui-sref="productsByCategory({
    slug: 'main-category/sub-category'
})">Sub category</a>
```

This still generates a url like `href="/products/main-category/sub-category"`

And now:

```
<a ui-sref="productsByCategory({
    slug: 'main-category'
})">Main category</a>
```

Generates `href="/products/main-category"` with no trailing slash :)

----EDIT----

Spoke too soon. It works as far as clicking the links in the browser works, but inspecting/copying the generated href shows the `/` is encoded. I still need a workaround like suggested here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/733

In the `UrlMatcher.prototype.format` method:

```
result += param.type.name == 'any' ? encoded : encodeURIComponent(encoded);
```

Comment: Note that while this fixes my problem it doesn't really answer my original question.